# Java XPath: Get all the elements that match a query

Tags: java, xml, xpath, namespaces, xml-namespaces

I want to make an XPath query on this XML file (excerpt shown):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- MetaDataAPI generated on: Friday, May 25, 2007 3:26:31 PM CEST -->
<Component xmlns="http://xml.sap.com/2002/10/metamodel/webdynpro" xmlns:IDX="urn:sap.com:WebDynpro.Component:2.0" mmRelease="6.30" mmVersion="2.0" mmTimestamp="1180099591892" name="MassimaleContr" package="com.bi.massimalecontr" masterLanguage="it">
...
    <Component.UsedModels>
        <Core.Reference package="com.test.test" name="MasterModel" type="Model"/>
        <Core.Reference package="com.test.massimalecontr" name="MassimaleModel" type="Model"/>
        <Core.Reference package="com.test.test" name="TravelModel" type="Model"/>
    </Component.UsedModels>
...
```

I'm using this snippet of code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(new File("E:\\Test branch\\test.wdcomponent"));
XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();

xpath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {
...(omitted)

System.out.println(xpath.evaluate(
    "//d:Component/d:Component.UsedModels/d:Core.Reference/@name", 
    document));
```

What I'm expecting to get:

```
MasterModel
MassimaleModel
TravelModel
```

What I'm getting:

```
MasterModel
```

It seems that only the first element is returned. How can I get all the occurrences that matches my query?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You'll get a item of type `NodeList`

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//Core.Reference");
NodeList list= (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = list.item(i);
    System.out.println(node.getTextContent());
    // work with node
```

Answer (score 4):

See [How to read XML using XPath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java)

As per that example, If you first compile the XPath expression then execute it, specifying that you want a NodeSet back you should get the result you want.